# How to figure out function prototype from assembly code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, assembly, reverse-engineering

I have some assembly code and I want to find out the calling function prototype, so that I can all the function from c++ code.

What I am really trying to do is to inject a dll into a running process and call the running process's functions form my dll. Right now I have successfully injected my dll but don't know how to do the 'calling'.

I am newbie and I only know a little about assembly code. My dll is written in visual c++ 2012.

Here is the code of the running process:

```
CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump          Command                                  Comments
6013BE24  /$  53            PUSH EBX
6013BE25  |.  8B1D 10461860 MOV EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[60184610]
6013BE2B  |.  8B1B          MOV EBX,DWORD PTR DS:[EBX]
6013BE2D  |.  8B40 04       MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+4]
6013BE30  |.  FFD3          CALL EBX
6013BE32  |.  5B            POP EBX
6013BE33  \.  C3            RETN
```

You can see at `6013BE30` it is calling the function, and the function(EBX) is at `004BAFAC`

```
CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump          Command                                  Comments
004BAFAC  /$  55            PUSH EBP                                 ; Test.004BAFAC(guessed void)
004BAFAD  |.  8BEC          MOV EBP,ESP
004BAFAF  |.  53            PUSH EBX
004BAFB0  |.  8BD8          MOV EBX,EAX
004BAFB2  |.  8B43 08       MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EBX+8]
004BAFB5  |.  E8 3EF40B00   CALL 0057A3F8                            ; [Test.0057A3F8
004BAFBA  |.  8B43 0C       MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EBX+0C]
004BAFBD  |.  E8 36F40B00   CALL 0057A3F8                            ; [Test.0057A3F8
004BAFC2  |.  8B43 14       MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EBX+14]
004BAFC5  |.  E8 2EF40B00   CALL 0057A3F8                            ; [Test.0057A3F8
004BAFCA  |.  8B43 18       MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EBX+18]
004BAFCD  |.  E8 26F40B00   CALL 0057A3F8                            ; [Test.0057A3F8
004BAFD2  |.  8B43 1C       MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EBX+1C]
004BAFD5  |.  E8 1EF40B00   CALL 0057A3F8                            ; [Test.0057A3F8
004BAFDA  |.  8B43 10       MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EBX+10]
004BAFDD  |.  E8 16F40B00   CALL 0057A3F8                            ; [Test.0057A3F8
004BAFE2  |.  8B43 20       MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EBX+20]
004BAFE5  |.  E8 0EF40B00   CALL 0057A3F8                            ; [Test.0057A3F8
004BAFEA  |.  8B43 44       MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EBX+44]
004BAFED  |.  E8 06F40B00   CALL 0057A3F8                            ; [Test.0057A3F8
004BAFF2  |.  8B43 44       MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EBX+44]
```

So how to call the function at `004BAFAC` from visual c++?

Comment: If you stick to primitive types like `int`, `char` you can almost interchange them, this might work even with pointers... But aren't you defining the types yourself?

Comment: @bash.d sorry what you mean 'defining the types'? All I have is those assembly code, you mean I have to know the arguments type first?

Comment: Yes, exactly, do you know the types you are passing?

Comment: What do you mean by "how to call the function"? It seems to take a pointer/array of some 32bit-type and then call another function using the elements of that array as parameters. If you pass an invalid pointer, or a pointer to invalid data, you are practically guaranteed to get segfaults.

Comment: @bash.d no. but from ollydbg at runtime, I can see some hints like "ptr to xxx", I guess these can help

Comment: @MickeyShine well, like I said, for primitive types it is insignificant (char, int). In assembly you are playing with addresses after all, there are no "real" datatypes... Try to stick with it...

Comment: @us2012 You mean the function argument is a pointer to something? I am not so familiar with assembly, but from the code it looks like so. "How to call the function" means how to call that function from C++, I really have no idea about that

Comment: @bash.d thank you for your comments. I'll keep trying

Answer (score 2):

In assembly function arguments are popped from the stack, starting with the last one. So to pass arguments to a function one pushes them to the stack first, then call the function. In MASM this would look something like that for showing a messagebox:

```
.data 
MsgBoxCaption  db "Attention",0 
MsgBoxText     db "Hello Message Box!",0 

.code
start:
push 0
mov eax, offset MsgBoxCaption
push eax
push offset MsgBoxText
push 0
call MessageBoxA
call ExitProcess
end start
```

Whilst in C++ it would look something like that:

```
int retval = MessageBox(NULL, "Hello Message Box!", "Attention", 0);
```

Disassembled with OllyDbg you'd get:

```
CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump          Command                                  Comments
011D13C0  |.  6A 00         PUSH 0                                   ; /Type = MB_OK|MB_DEFBUTTON1|MB_APPLMODAL
011D13C2  |.  68 54571D01   PUSH OFFSET 011D5754                     ; |Caption = "Attention"
011D13C7  |.  68 3C571D01   PUSH OFFSET 011D573C                     ; |Text = "Hello Message Box!"
011D13CC  |.  6A 00         PUSH 0                                   ; |hOwner = NULL
011D13CE  |.  FF15 40831D01 CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&USER32.MessageBoxA> ; \USER32.MessageBoxA
```

The return value gets stored in eax. You see that in case of datatypes bigger than a DWORD (4 bytes) you are not actually passing values but references. Each argument is actually just a DWORD. That is because the stack is 32 bit aligned in a 32 bit system, and therefore can only hold 32 bit values. The same is the case for the registers. In a 32 bit system registers are 32 bit wide. If you pass a string you are passing a reference to the string, not the string nor a variable width array of characters/bytes. In case of an Integer it will most likely be passed as value, not reference. When prototyping functions in MASM prototyping all parameters as DWORD will work (not in C++ tho).

So in your example above it *seems like* there is one parameter getting passed onto the stack (push ebx). I say *seems like* because it could very well just be that ebx is pushed to store it for later retrieval (i.e. after the call ebx is popped again - maybe the value stored in ebx needed to be preserved). You can only tell for sure when actually running a live debugging session and observing the stack/registers. Step over the call and check your **stack pointer** (esp) before and after to see how many arguments are passed to the function (again: 1 argument = 1 DWORD = 4 bytes).

To prototype your function in C++ you will need to figure out what datatype the argument is, possibly by single-stepping through the assembly code and checking the registers and/or the stack while traversing the code around the function in question. The same holds true for the return value in eax. So eax will never hold a string, but rather possibly a reference to a string, but it might hold a 32 bit or smaller integer. You'd have to find out what kind of data eax points to by reversing the surrounding code as well.

*EDIT: Actually half the stuff I wrote was wrong, most notably parameters always being references, so please reread what I have written. Sorry for the inconvenience - shouldnt answer questions being tired :)*

Comment: Sounds like the right routine. I'll try to follow what you said, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Without more detail, it's really difficult to tell what's going on. Due to the unusual code, I suspect that the app has been obfuscated. You might have better luck with IDA.

The short answer is that all the functions seem to take a pointer-to-something in `eax` (`0057A3F8` might take a 4-byte integer instead). It's difficult to tell what these are pointers to. You will probably need an assembly helper to call these from C++.

---

First you need to work out the calling convention: Both `6013BE24` and `004BAFAC` appear to take a single argument in `eax`, which according to [this list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#List_of_x86_calling_conventions) is only used by Borland (fastcall), Watcom (by default), or Embarcadero Delphi. You haven't said if the app you're reverse-engineering is written in C++, but even if it is, I think you'll have difficulty calling without a little assembly.

`6013BE24` appears look up a function in a function table with something like `ebx=**(void***)0x60184610` (I forget what pointer-to-pointer-to-function-pointer looks like); I'd see if this pointed to a relocation table somewhere. It also takes a pointer to a struct in `eax` (something like `struct Foo { void * dummy; Bar * bar; ... }`) and then does roughly `return ebx(eax->bar)`. I don't know if it actually returns anything, but it will return anything returned in registers. I don't know why it uses `ebx` instead of a register that doesn't need to be preserved.

`004BAFAC` sets up a stack frame, preserves `ebx`, and then does makes a few calls to `0057A3F8` with things in `bar` (i.e. eax). If `bar` is a `void**`, it'd look something like `f(bar[2]); f(bar[3]); f(bar[5]); f(bar[6]); f(bar[7]); f(bar[4]); f(bar[8]); f(bar[17]);` and then it loads `bar[17]` again (and there the disassembly ends). I suspect `bar` is actually a struct of some sort.

`0057A3F8` appears to take a single argument in `eax`.

Comment: The target process is written with delphi(might be delphi 2007, not sure). I am reading about the 'calling convention' thing. Thank you for your comment!